# Print ObservableList or Grid

Tags: java, javafx

I have found this code which generate a grid for a spreadsheatview in java, it is working nicely but I am not sure how to print the grid, like print cells by number of row and column

```
int rowCount = 10;
int columnCount = 2;
GridBase grid = new GridBase(rowCount, columnCount);

ObservableList<ObservableList<SpreadsheetCell>> rows = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
for (int row = 0; row < grid.getRowCount(); ++row) {
    final ObservableList<SpreadsheetCell> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    for (int column = 0; column < grid.getColumnCount(); ++column) 
    {
        if(row == 1)
        list.add(SpreadsheetCellType.STRING.createCell(row, column, 1, 1,"Hello"));
        else
            list.add(SpreadsheetCellType.STRING.createCell(row, column, 1, 1,"Not"));   
    }
    rows.add(list);
}
grid.setRows(rows);
spreadsheet.setGrid(grid);
```

And here is the spreadsheetView 
[image]

I just want to handle these values by row and column and process them, so for instance anyone know how can I print the first cell?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't sure to ask ObservableList or Grid to print cells, but I tried this way and it worked very well

```
SpreadsheetCell cell = rows.get(3).get(3);
System.out.println(cell.getText());
```

it prints any cell by row and column.